# Counting Odd and Even numbers in a comma-separated list

Tags: excel

I have a list of comma-separated numbers (positive,single or double digits) in A1. 
The list can only contain up to 20 numbers, can be less but not more.

Is there a formula to count the even and odd numbers in the cell without separating the list in to different cells? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Even:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISEVEN(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))
```

Odd:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISODD(--MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The quantity of odd numbers (put this in cell B1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),1+LEN(A1)*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1))-1),LEN(A1)),2))
```

The quantity of even numbers (references the result of the previous formula, which is assumed to be in cell B1):

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""))+1-B1
```